# Issue deploying smart contract from remix to azure blockchain - error

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I have a smart contract that I would like to connect to my azure ethereum blockchain. It's compiled and ready to go.  My Ethereum blockchain is live on Azure. I am erroring out on the remix side in efforts to deploy the smart contract to the Azure ethereum blockchain.

I am working on an http connection from remix to the ethereum rpc endpoint.  I connected Metamask on my browser to the endpoint.  I'm using Web3 provider.

I am getting the Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

So far I'm wondering if there is anything I can add to the code or in the remix console to make this work.  I'm on the Brave browser with the Metamask extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your web3 connection on azure return null instance due to which it generate this error. 
 install web3 on azure instance and connect your application with azure endpoint. it will then works.